# `dict_values` is hashable but `dict_keys` is not?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.10

I just found out that `d.values()` (for some dict `d`) appears to be hashable not matter the type of the values.
However, `d.keys()` appears to be unhashable, although the elements are guaranteed to be
hashable.

Here is an example:

```
d1 = {'d': 0, 'a': 1, 'e': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 4}
d2 = {0: [], 1: [[]], 2: [[[]]], 3: [[[[]]]]}
```

now

```
print(hash(d1.values()))
print(hash(d2.values()))
```

Work fine and print some numerical values.
But,

```
print(hash(d1.keys()))
```

and

```
print(hash(d2.keys()))
```

both throw `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict_keys'`.

I would have expected the exact opposite! Now I'm curious about the reason why Python does this that way.